# How do C++ and Java communicate with each other?

Tags: java, c++

Is there any program/software which uses both C++ and Java?

If so the how do they communicate with each other?

The theory and the program please.

Example: Supposing I want to run a C++ file with a Java applet or something like that.

Comment: [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html#wp9502)

Comment: Look for [JNI](http://www.pacifier.com/~mmead/cs510jip/jni/)

Comment: Thanks a lot johnchen902 and g-makulik.

Doing that only. Seems that I have found my answer for Java. If I have to do the same with C++ then what do I do?

Comment: @PrakharMohan See Chapter 5 of link I gave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Java Native Interface**

Pro: Fast way to call a C++ library from Java and the other way around.

Contra: You need control over the library to make it support JNI.

**Creating a process from Java and communicate with it via input- and output streams**

Pro: Binary is running in a separate thread. Binary can be implemented in any programming language which allows command-line based input and output.

Contra: Data exchange is text-based. You are limited to what the taget application can do via command line interface.

**Make two applications communicate via network sockets**

Pro: Application can be implemented in any technology which supports network sockets. You can easily move the component to another machine to improve scalability. The marketing department can call it "Cloud Powered".

Contra: Application must be network-based. Even when running locally, the detour over the network stack of the OS introduces additional latencies. Security measures must be taken to not allow an unauthorized client to connect to the component which acts as server.